# -logy: Word for "the study of humour"

Tags: terminology

I'm searching for the correct word for:

> "The branch of knowledge and research concerned with funniness / what
> people find funny / what makes people laugh"

Generally such words are suffixed with "-logy" which roughly denotes "a branch of knowledge/study of a particular subject."  from -logia, "study", "research".

e.g

- astrology
- sociology
- geology
- philology
- ecology

etc.

I could only find "humourology", but that doesn't seem as though its the "official designation".
Thank you for reading

Comment: I see only *humor studies* as the name of the field.

Comment: _Humorology_, the study or science of humour, _is_ given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/humorology), but flagged as rare.

Comment: There is, alas, no such word, though there is a crying need for such studies.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humor_research) says *humor studies* or *humor research*. There doesn't seem to be a word for the study of tragedy either.

Comment: As an aside, Gelotology (from the Greek γέλως gelos "laughter")is the study of laughter and its effects on the body, from a psychological and physiological perspective. See Wikipedia: Gelotology

Comment: I came up with the word "comicology", but when I tried googling it it was "corrected"  to "comiXology", which is a web site devoted to comic books.